# View is callable still getting error View must be Callable-Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, django-urls

Hi I am writing my first Django program. I am getting this error:

```
            url(r'^hello/',view.Users().getUsers(), name='hello')
File"C:\Users\jayant.brahmchari\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\si
   te-packages\django\conf\urls\__init__.py", line 85, in url
   raise TypeError('view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of 
   include().')
   TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().
```

this is my urls.py:

```
      from django.conf.urls import url
      from django.contrib import admin
      from . import view

      urlpatterns = [
      url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
      url(r'^hello/',view.Users().getUsers(), name='hello')
      ]
```

this is view.py:

```
        from django.http import HttpResponse


        class Users:
           def getUsers(self):
               return HttpResponse("Hello Users")
```

According to people in forums url do not accept string as second argument but in my code view is already callable but still getting this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are calling the function so you end up with result. Remove parentheses `()` from here `view.Users().getUsers`

Comment: worked thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

what you are trying to do something does not exists.

In your urls you simple do

`url(r'^hello/$',view.get_users, name='hello')`

and on your views simply add the function without the class

`def get_users(request):
    return HttpResponse("hello users")`

I recommend you to do the django tutorial on the django website (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/)

I hope it helps

Best Hélio

Comment: Class based view provide better code reusability. All django view need not to be a function.

Answer (score 0):

The error is suggesting true. You are passing the result of the method call to the url() function. Try passing the method reference as`view.Users().getUsers` rather than the calling the `getUsers()` function in place